# can I make shared library using gfortran?

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, f2py

I would like to make so file in order to use it in python.
how can I make shared library from fortran source?

I have tested like below code.

```
gfortran -c mod.f90
#gfortran -c sub1.f90
gfortran -c func.f90
gfortran -shared -fPIC -o func.so func.f90 mod.o
```

but I couldn't import it in python. I used module file in fortran source code. and I imported fortran source code from python. I'm not sure if I do right.

```
[===>14:47:59]f1:python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import func
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initfunc)




func.f90
-----------------------------------------
program func

use mod_test

switch1 = .true.
switch2 = .false.

x = 1.2
!call test(x, z)
print *, b, str, z, switch1, switch2

!print *, 'hello'
end program func
-----------------------------------------
mod.f90
-----------------------------------------
module mod_test
!implicit none
integer a
real x, y, z
real*8 :: b = 3.4
logical*2 switch1, switch2
character*5, parameter :: str = 'good'
end module mod_test
-----------------------------------------
sub1.f90
-----------------------------------------
subroutine test(input, output)
real, intent(in) :: input
real, intent(out) :: output

output = (input + input)
end subroutine
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: I also tested : fwrapc func.f90 --build --name=func --fcompiler=gnu95 --f90exec=/usr/bin/gfortran-4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6 -lgfortran but it cannot find the module.

Answer (score 11):

You need some "glue" between Fortran and Python. Check out [F2PY - Fortran to Python interface generator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html)

EDIT. Example:

```
f2py -c -m func func.f90 mod.f90 sub1.f90
python
>>> import func
>>> dir(func)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__version__', 'mod_test', 'test']
```

EDIT 2. If you want to execute the code in func.f90 from Python, I think you must change it from program to a subroutine.

Comment: f2py -c mod.f90; f2py -c -m func func.f90; I did like this but the module couldn't be found..how can I do?

Comment: "the module couldn't be found" -- is that an error message from f2py?

Comment: f2py -c -m func func.f90 mod.f90 sub1.f90 is to create executable file. but I want to make a shared library in order to import it from Python. and the error message was from Python : ImportError: ./func.so: undefined symbol: __mod_test_MOD_b

Comment: @wonjun A shared library func.so is exactly what `f2py -c -m func` builds for you. Maybe some results from you previous attempts interfere. Copy the three f90 files to an empty subdirectory and try again there.

Comment: I could make so file but the subroutine test in sub1.f90. cannot be called in Python. >>> import func
>>> dir(func)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', 'mod_test']

Comment: For me, dir(func) includes 'test'.

Comment: I called it from fortran like this : call test(x, z) and in python, ImportError: ./func.so: undefined symbol: test_